# Swagger implementation spring boot Oauth2 issue : 404 409

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am implementing swagger 2 in my application (spring boot), so i have oauth2 implemented and it gives me `bearer token_id` then only all api will be authenticated.

SO, my swagger page is actually there

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jj3F.png)

as you can see i am getting nothing in this page
my SwaggerConfig.java file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("OSAM")
                .description("OSAM")
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                .version("1.0.0").contact(new Contact("","", "pb@gmail.com"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securitySchema(), apiKey()));
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {

        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList();
        GrantType passwordCredentialsGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant("tokenUrl");
        grantTypes.add(passwordCredentialsGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Authorization",
                "api_key", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/anyPath.*"))
                .build();
    }

    List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
                = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Lists.newArrayList(
                new SecurityReference("Authorization", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(null, null, null, null, "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER,"Authorization",": Bearer");
    }
}
```

I am using these version (with jdk 8) because greater than 2.7.0 it was giving me some pop-up in html

```
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-annotations
    compile group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-annotations', version: '1.5.22'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.0.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-bean-validators
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-bean-validators', version: '2.7.0'
```

My question is : What i am missing? How to resolve that 404,409 error,
in the image provided, it is saying 404 409 for several apis how to fix it in spring boot?
any help would be really really appreciated.